# Does differentiation widen, or narrow, the class of functions?

Tags: polynomials, differential-calculus

Let $\cal F^k$ be a set of functions, each of class $C^k$,
i.e., both, for every function in $\cal F^k$:

- $k^{\textrm{th}}$ derivatives exist, and
- are continuous.

Let $D(\cal F^k)$ be the set of all those functions' derivatives,
up to the $k^\textrm{th}$ derivative.

My basic question is:

> ***Q0***. What is the relation between $\cal F^k$ and $D(\cal F^k)$ ?

If $\cal F^k$ is the set of all univariant polynomials of at most degree $k$,
then $D(\cal F^k)$ is the polynomials of degree at most $k{-}1$.

> ***Q1***. Is there, in general, 
>   a nice structural relationship between $\cal F$ and $D( \cal F)$ ?

What I am really seeking to answer is this (from the title):

> ***Q2***. Does differentiation widen, or narrow—or neither!—the class of functions $\cal{F}$?

Perhaps $D( \cal F) \subseteq \cal{F}$ ?

(One could replace "differentiation" with "integration" and ask
analogous questions.)

Comment: There is not always a clear relationship, especially when your class is very small.  Consider k=1 and D(F) having just the absolute value function, so F just has one function.  If you put other conditions on F, such as it is a vector space of large dimension, then it might get more interesting and useful.  Gerhard "What Relationships Do You Want?" Paseman, 2016.01.02

Comment: The impression students may get from a calculus class is the complete opposite of what analysts know well: differentiation tends to make functions worse while integration makes them better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer depends on the class you consider. If $F^k=C^k$, the class of all
functions with your properties, then $D(F^k)=C^{k-1}$,
and $C^k$ is a proper subset of $D(F^k)$. If $F^k$ is the class of all polynomials, then $D(F^k)=F^k$. If $F^k$ is the class of polynomials of degree at most $d$, then $D(F^k)$ is a proper subset of $F^k$.